# Object not moving in correct direction

Tags: java, android, math, libgdx

Alright, I'm trying to do some simple object moving in the direction of where you touched the screen.

If I touch directly northwest of the object, it'll kind of move into the direction of the touch position.  If I touch directly southeast of the object, it will kind of move into the direction of the touch position as well.  However, if I touch directly northeast of the object, it'll move into the opposite direction towards the southwest.  If I touch directly southwest of the object, it'll also move to the opposite direction towards northeast.

Also, if I touch north of the object, but just a little to the west, it will go straight west with a little to the north.  Same with touching west of the object with a little bit to the north, it'll go straight north with a little bit to the west.  Same thing for other directions.

Really, all the directions are from somewhat to obviously incorrect.  I've been doing some paper calculations as well and I've seemed to be getting some correct angles, but at this point I'm completely stumped.

Does anyone know what the problem may be?

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames.texasholdem;

import java.util.List;

import android.util.FloatMath;

import com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.Game;
import com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.Graphics;
import com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.Input.TouchEvent;
import com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.Screen;

public class MainMenuScreen extends Screen {
    public static float TO_RADIANS = (1 / 180.0f) * (float) Math.PI;
    public static float TO_DEGREES = (1 / (float) Math.PI) * 180;
    float num_x = 0; // Position of object on X axis
    float num_y = 0; // Position of object on Y axis
    float angle = 0;

    public MainMenuScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);               
    }

    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();
        game.getInput().getKeyEvents();       

        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if(event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
                if(inBounds(event, 0, 0, g.getWidth(), g.getHeight()) ) {

                    // Calculate the angle of the direction between two points
                    angle = (float) Math.atan2(event.x - num_x, event.y - num_y) * TO_DEGREES; 
                    if (angle < 0)
                        angle += 360;

                    // This is just to give me numbers on the Math.atan2 result, angle, to/from X position, and to/from Y position
                    System.out.println("Pressed! - ATAN: " + Math.atan2(event.x - num_x, event.y - num_y)
                        + " - ANGLE:" + angle + " - POS: " + event.x + "tx/"
                        + (int)num_x + "fx " + event.y + "ty/" + (int)num_y + "fy");
                }
            }
        }
        // Moving object in direction at 1f speed
        num_x += (1f * (float) Math.cos(angle * TO_RADIANS));
        num_y += (1f * (float) Math.sin(angle * TO_RADIANS));
    }

    private boolean inBounds(TouchEvent event, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        if(event.x > x && event.x < x + width - 1 && 
           event.y > y && event.y < y + height - 1) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void present(float deltaTime) {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        g.drawPixmap(Assets.background, 0, 0);
        g.drawPixmap(Assets.backcard, (int)num_x, (int)num_y);
    }

    public void pause() {        
        Settings.save(game.getFileIO());
    }

    public void resume() {

    }

    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if event x> x then x must be positive to move toward event.x

the problem here is that when event.x< x then your moving x must be negative

```
int dx,dy;



 dx = (1f * (float) Math.cos(angle * TO_RADIANS));
        dy = (1f * (float) Math.sin(angle * TO_RADIANS));

if(event.x<x){
dx=-dx;}
if(event.y<y){
dy=-dy;}


num_x+=dx;
num_y+=dy;
```

this way is simpler but less precise....

```
public void update(){
    //(find dif between item x, and touch x)
    float xdif=destx-x;
    float ydif=desty-y;

    if(x<destx){

        dx=xdif/8;
        }

    else if(x>destx){
        //we devide both x and y differences by the same number
        dx=xdif/8;
        }

    else if(x==destx){
        dx=0;
        }
    if(y<desty){
        dy=ydif/5;
        }
    else if(y>desty){
        dy=ydif/5;
        }
    else if(y==desty){
        dy=0;
        }

    x+=dx;
    y+=dy;
```

there u go, pathing in a straight line between two points, item.x and touch x.

Comment: The first one doesn't seem to be working very well, I might have to double check it later.  The second part I want to avoid to use.  Precise direction is important.

Comment: you can buff the second one up wuith your math i just left it simple so u can see the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, the math - I think the problem is that, for example, `tan(135deg) = tan (-45deg) = -1`. Therefore, `atan` has return values ranging between -90deg and 90deg as a resolution to ambiguity ([look at its graph here](http://intmstat.com/analytic-trigonometry/arctanx.gif)). I think La5t5tarfighter's solution - negating the x movement in some cases - is on the right track, but you need to negate the y component in those cases as well. You could try that, but it would be much simpler if you used libGDX's `Vector2` class. This is how I'd do it:

```
move.set(touchX, touchY);  // y should be through flipping or unproject() before this
move.sub(objectPos);       // move now points from object to where you touched
move.nor();                // now 1 unit long
move.scl(SPEED*deltaTime); // multiplied by a constant and delta - framerate-independent
objectPos.add(move);
```

You could even chain it into just one line if you want:

```
objectPos.add(move.set(x,y).sub(objectPos).nor().scl(SPEED*deltaTime));
```

**Secondly**, you're not using a `Camera`. I'm not completely sure what the default coordinate system is, but I believe the y axis points up which is not the same as the one used for inputs - `Input.getY()` is given with an y axis pointing down from the top left corner. If you had a `Camera`, you'd do this:

```
cam.unproject(someVector.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
```

Lacking that, you might need to flip the y axis:

```
event.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - event.y;
```

Still, this could be wrong. Try drawing the object right at the touch position - if I'm right in this, it'll seem mirrored vertically. If it draws correctly where you touch, ignore this part.